# Getting file from sdcard with Uri

Tags: android, file, filenotfoundexception

I let the user select a file from the sdcard to upload to my server and save the `Uri` that gets returned to me in `onActivityResult`

example:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/menu-4.27.13.pdf
```

when I try to convert it to a byte array to send to the server I get the `FileNotFoundException`

```
if(!fileURI.equals("")){
    File pdf = new File(fileURI);
    try 
    {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(pdf);

        byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)pdf.length()];
        fin.read(fileContent);
        fin.close();

        String pdfString = Base64.encode(fileContent);
        sb.append(pdfString);
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();                      
    }
}

}
```

stack trace

```
11-04 11:57:30.597: W/System.err(13531): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/storage/emulated/0/Download/menu-4.27.13.pdf: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-04 11:57:30.597: W/System.err(13531):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
11-04 11:57:30.607: W/System.err(13531):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
11-04 11:57:30.607: W/System.err(13531):    at com.ecm2.mobilemap.services.MessageService.getModifiedElements(MessageService.java:2755)
11-04 11:57:30.617: W/System.err(13531):    at com.ecm2.mobilemap.services.MessageService.callSync(MessageService.java:2433)
11-04 11:57:30.617: W/System.err(13531):    at com.ecm2.mobilemap.services.MessageService.onHandleIntent(MessageService.java:190)
11-04 11:57:30.627: W/System.err(13531):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
11-04 11:57:30.627: W/System.err(13531):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 11:57:30.637: W/System.err(13531):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 11:57:30.637: W/System.err(13531):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
11-04 11:57:30.637: W/System.err(13531): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-04 11:57:30.647: W/System.err(13531):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
11-04 11:57:30.657: W/System.err(13531):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
11-04 11:57:30.657: W/System.err(13531):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
```

is that not what the `File` objects as a string when its initialized? Why am I getting the `FileNotFoundException` when I have the `Uri` returned to me when the user selected the file

Comment: May be you could use Content Resolver

See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021528/open-file-from-uri-independent-of-location-in-android

Comment: File path "/file:/storage/emulated/0/Download/menu-4.27.13.pdf" from logs is incorrect. May be you are using incorrect way to get the file path.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `Uri` contains the `file:` scheme, which you need to remove. Using `Uri.parse`, you figure the Uri contained in your String, using `uri.getPath()`, you extract the file path from the uri :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(fileURI);
File pdf = new File(uri.getPath());
```

Comment: This took me ages to find the answer for, but it's obvious when you think about. Thank you

Comment: What is fileURI In this case?

Comment: @KalaJ: cf the question: example:

`file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/menu-4.27.13.pdf`

Comment: You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, maybe the file is not present or the path is wrong. 
See the stack trace. The first line itself tells the whole problem. Try accessing some other file and parse the filePath first using URI