# FileNotFoundException when try to generate PDF in android

Tags: java, android, pdf, pdf-generation, android-logcat

In here i'm try to generate a pdf file in android, but in the run time i get  this execption

```
       ioException:java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/PDF/Demo.pdf: openfailed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

this is my code

```
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
     import java.io.IOException;
    import com.lowagie.text.Document;
    import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException; 
    import com.lowagie.text.Font;
    import com.lowagie.text.HeaderFooter;
    import com.lowagie.text.Image;
    import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
    import com.lowagie.text.Phrase;
      import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

      public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button createPDF , openPDF;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createPDF = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        createPDF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                createPDF();
            }
        });
        openPDF = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        openPDF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                openPdf();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void createPDF(){
        Document doc  =new Document();
        try {
            String parth = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDF";
            File dir = new File(parth);
            if(!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdir();
            Log.d("PDFCreater", "PDF PARTH "+parth);
            File file = new File(dir,"demo.pdf");
            Log.d("PDFCreater", "Create");
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            Log.d("PDFCreater", "1");
            PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);
            Log.d("PDFCreater", "2");
            doc.open();
            Log.d("PDFCreater", "open");
            Paragraph p1= new Paragraph("Customer History");
            Font paraFont = new Font(Font.HELVETICA);
            paraFont.setSize(16);
            p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
            p1.setFont(paraFont);
            doc.add(p1);
            Log.d("PDFCreater", "add");
            /* Inserting Image in PDF */
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(), R.drawable.apple);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , stream);
            Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

            //add image to document
            doc.add(myImg);
            Phrase footerText = new Phrase("This is an example of a footer");
            HeaderFooter pdfFooter = new HeaderFooter(footerText, false);
            doc.setFooter(pdfFooter);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
        } 
        finally
        {
            doc.close();
        }



    }
    void openPdf()
    {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDF";

    File file = new File(path, "demo.pdf");
    intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile( file ), "application/pdf" );
       startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

here is my xml file

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="Create" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:text="Open" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.isuru.mypdf"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.isuru.mypdf.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I think that the exception throws on this line

```
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

please help me , thank you !

Comment: `ENOENT (No such file or directory)` <-- the file is not where you expect it to be. I know `FileNotFoundException` sucks, but at least its message is clear enough about what happens here. And yes, you think correctly. If you are still stuck with Java 6, `file.exists()` would hopefully return `false`.

Comment: Did you give your app the permission to write to the external storage?

Comment: Where's the rest of the stacktrace? What you posted is not all the stacktrace! Like Daniel said, you'll need this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` permission added to your AndroidManifest file. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) for more info and read about the caveat for API 19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you declared this permission in the android manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: @Octopus If you don't have permissions to read files then how can you make folder in it?

Comment: So, you are saying that the expected file wouldn't have been created due to permission problem. Am i right?

Comment: yeah true that is what

Comment: thanks a lot, yes i haven't add above cording for my manifest file,now when i creating my pdf file using addroid app there are no errors, but when i open my pdf file using android app it will give me en error                                  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/sdcard/PDF/demo.pdf typ=application/pdf }                      what was the problem, please help me thank you

Comment: @user3276345 You didn't mentioned activity in the manifest file of application tag. So you must and should add that activity in manifest other wise it will through that exception

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.isuru.mypdf"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.isuru.mypdf.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

Comment: @shylendra i have no experience by giving permissions on android applications i have post my android manifest file,so what should i have to modify on that, i'm  very happy that you ask manifest file try to help me.Thanks a lot ,please help me to solve this error.Thank you

Comment: Here you are trying to start an intent but there is no another activity to start from that intent. So that is why here you getting that activity not found exception, for that you need to create new activity and put code of open pdf file in that.and try

Comment: please help me to implement that part ,in the first line i give the parth and the name of the pdf file,                               File file = new File(path, "demo.pdf");      then how to open it and show that pdf file please help me , thank you

Comment: thank you , every one  now i solve the problem ,  ActivityNotFoundException come because i haven't install the wanted plugins for my emulator, now it works correctly thanks for every one who help me to solve my problem from the beginning ,

Answer (score 1):

Add read and write permission in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Check here:

[Getting file from sdcard with Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772856/getting-file-from-sdcard-with-uri)

Comment: thanks a lot yes i haven't add above cording for my manifest file,now when i creating my pdf file there are no errors, but when i open my pdf file it will give me en error                                                                    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/sdcard/PDF/demo.pdf typ=application/pdf }                                                                     what was the problem, please help me thank you

Comment: Check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772856/getting-file-from-sdcard-with-uri

Comment: thank you , but i'm get an error call ActivityNotFoundException so what and where i have to modify that , thanks for helping to solve my problem

Comment: in that cord thay use some thing like this                           Uri uri = Uri.parse(fileURI);
File pdf = new File(uri.getPath()); ////////////////// but i use like this                            intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile( file ), "application/pdf"  startActivity(intent); what was the different of these lines and can u please expand above cording

Comment: void openPdf(){Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDF";
File file = new File(path, "demo.pdf");
intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile( file ), "application/pdf" );
startActivity(intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile( file ), "application/pdf" ));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
Intent target = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File");
try {startActivity(target);} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
Log.e("PDFCreator", "ActivityNotFoundException:" + e);} }

Comment: Please Edit Question with Log Cat

Comment: i modify openpdf  method like above cording still the error there

Comment: thank you , every one  now i solve the problem ,  ActivityNotFoundException come because i haven't install the wanted plugins for my emulator, now it works correctly thanks for every one who help me to solve my problem from the beginning ,